# Error while upgrading from IBM BPM 8.5.7 to IBM BPM 8.6.0?

Tags: websphere, ibm-bpm

I have IBM BPM 8.5.7 build label 20160301 installed and the database is sql server 2012, now i need to upgrade it to IBM BPM 8.6.0. So to achieve this I am following I am following below procedure.

1. Stopped deployment manager, node and server.
2. I took backup of database and profiles.
3. Applied WAS 11 fix pack.
4. Running below command to upgrade WAS 12 and BPM 8.6.0

Command:

```
imcl install com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85 com.ibm.bpm.STD.v85,BPMServerSTD.NonProduction -acceptLicense -installationDirectory "C:\IBM\BPM\v8.5" -repositories D:\Softwares\BPMUpgrade860Was,D:\Softwares\BPMUpgrade860 -log silent_update.txt -properties user.wasjava=java8 -showVerboseProgress
```

But after running for long time it fails with below error.

```
<error>
    Error during &quot;install&quot; phase:
  </error>
  <error>
    Deleting files from C:\IBM\BPM\v8.5
  </error>
  <error>
    Failed to delete C:\IBM\BPM\v8.5\BPM\QuickStart\launchpad.exe
  </error>
```

I am missing something here?

Plan to upgrade sdk 8 was after above command gets successfully completed. I also tried sdk 8 with the same above command but the issue is same.

Comment: Did you checked that file `launchpad.exe`? Maybe it is still running in the background or you dont have rights to remove it.

Comment: yes that was the issue I restarted my system and the issue is fixed. thanks